# Manual slideshow not working as intended

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on revamping a webpage for a local montessori. I am attempting to use the manual slideshow script, however, the page is not working as intended. Without adding an "onload" attribute, every image in the slideshow is displayed at once. Upon inspection, I have an error stating: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined". Here is the HTML section in question:

```
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 8</div>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/hOlkQyd.jpg" width = "800" height = "600"/>
      <div class="text">Caption One</div>
   </div>

   <div class="mySlides fade">
     <div class="numbertext">2 / 8</div>
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/79juKeU.jpg" width = "800" height = "600"/>
     <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
   </div>

   <div class="mySlides fade">
     <div class="numbertext">3 / 8</div>
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/54B3yvz.jpg" width = "800" height = "600"/>
     <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
   </div>

   <div class="mySlides fade">
     <div class="numbertext">4 / 8</div>
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/zsvuaoU.jpg" width = "800" height = "600"/>
     <div class="text">Caption Four</div>
   </div>

   <div class="mySlides fade">
     <div class="numbertext">5 / 8</div>
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/N2hgBtH.jpg" width = "800" height = "600"/>
     <div class="text">Caption Five</div>
   </div>

   <div class="mySlides fade">
     <div class="numbertext">6 / 8</div>
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/McQHME4.jpg" width = "800" height = "600"/>
     <div class="text">Caption Six</div>
   </div>

   <div class="mySlides fade">
     <div class="numbertext">7 / 8</div>
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/rOvbBlj.jpg" width = "800" height = "600"/>
     <div class="text">Caption Seven</div>
   </div>

   <div class="mySlides fade">
     <div class="numbertext">8 / 8</div>
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/aX4kzGr.jpg" width = "800" height = "600"/>
     <div class="text">Caption Eight</div>
   </div>

   <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
   <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
 </div>

 <div style="text-align:center">
   <span class="dot active" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
   <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
   <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
   <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span> 
   <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span> 
   <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(6)"></span> 
   <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(7)"></span> 
   <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(8)"></span>  
 </div>
```

Here is the script:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n)
{
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n)
{
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n)
{
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1;} 
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length;}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++)
    {
        slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++)
    {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; /*Error appears here */
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: In order to find any help you should the problematic script, inform us about what libraries you use and post the html code that should be affected, prefferably all within a snippet that isolates your problem. Your question is too broad to find hel the way it is right now.

Comment: The question was mistakenly posted unfinished when I was forming it. The question is complete now.

Comment: Is the script loaded before or after the slide contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; /*Error appears here */
```

The reason why `slides[slideIndex-1]` would be undefined is if `slideIndex - 1` is beyond the bounds of `slides`. The most likely cause is that `slides` is *empty*. This could occur if you're running your script before the page content instead of after. This would cause this line to make `slides` length zero, since there are not yet *any* elements with the class name `mySlides`:

```
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
```

Moving your script tag *after* the slide content should resolve the issue, or moving the `showSlides(slideIndex)` call in an `onload` handler.

Comment: The script in question was contained in the head of the document. After moving it to the very end of the body, the script now works correctly. I will also try the onload handler to see if I get a similar result.